# Name a ScatterViewItem programmatically

Tags: c#, pixelsense, scatterview

Currently I'm working on the Microsoft Surface primarily creating an application that dynamically creates ScatterViewItems based on a database (Though not binded, for reasons that are unimportant to the question.) My problem comes when I try to register a Name to an SVI with a ScatterView before placing it in the control.

Declaring the NameScope:

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(ActionArea, new NameScope());
```

Creating/Assigning the SVI a name

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,Node> i in nodes)
{
    ScatterViewItem item = new ScatterViewItem();
    item.Content = i.Value.Argument;
    item.Tag = i.Value;
    ActionArea.RegisterName("NodeID" + i.Key.ToString(), item);
    ActionArea.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Calling the name later on

```
ScatterViewItem to = (ScatterViewItem)ActionArea.FindName(name);
```

When this is called, FindName returns null. From this (and looking at the SVI's Name property) I can only conclude I'm assigning the name wrong.

So how do you assign a name to a programmatically created object?

Comment: Nevermind, it was code unrelated to naming stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about NameScope - very very rarely needed.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,Node> i in nodes)
{    
   ScatterViewItem item = new ScatterViewItem();    
   item.Content = i.Value.Argument;    
   item.Tag = i.Value;    
   item.Name = "NodeID" + i.Key.ToString(); // set the name property
   ActionArea.Items.Add(item);
}
```